# Laravel TDD ignored URL query params when trying to catch them in Controller with request

Tags: php, laravel, tdd

I would like to write a test to be sure my query parameters in URL are working fine. But whenever I do a `request()->all()`, I got an empty array.

Here is my test part:

```
public function test_it_should_paginate_the_results_when_perPage_query_is_used()
{
    // Given
    factory('App\Order', 17)->create();

    // When
    // $request = $this->call('GET', route('api.orders.index'), ['perPage' => '5']);
    // $request = $this->call('GET', route('api.orders.index') . '?perPage=5', ['perPage' => '5']);
    $request = $this->get(route('api.orders.index') . '?perPage=5');

    // Then
    $request->assertJsonCount(5);
}
```

And here is the basic method in OrderController:

```
public function index()
{
    dd(request()->all());
    $orders = Order::all();
    return $orders;
}
```

Did I miss something ?

---

I've forgot to mention that it picks up the parameters in the browser, but not in PHPUnit test tool

**UPDATED QUESTION**

So I found out a problem. It does not working when you are testing with `php artisan test` command. It works only when you are using `phpunit` command.

No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data as the second argument to `route()` or as the third argument to `call()`:

```
$request = $this->get(route('api.orders.index', ['perPage' => 5]));
$request = $this->call('GET', route('api.orders.index', ['perPage' => 5]));
$request = $this->call('GET', route('api.orders.index'), ['perPage' => 5]);
```

Here are the defintions:

```
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)

public function call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
```

Comment: That's what I did already, it's not picking up the parameters at all.